# Writing text and intergers to a file, then reading from the file to calculate grade averages

Tags: python, file-io, average

This is what I am trying to display. These are the by products of 2 functions.
The first paragraph is the create() function which creates the "grades.txt" file. I think I got down pretty easily.

Secondly, the next paragraph is from the "Retrieve()" function reading from the "grades.txt" file and displaying the class name and GPA then calculating average for those classes and displaying them.
I feel like Im right at the cusp but im stuck as to where to go from here because im plagued with "STRG" errors.

```js
 >     def main ():
    >         create()
    >         retrieve()
    >         
    >     def create():
    >             outfile = open('grades.txt', 'w')
    >             count_files = 0
    >     
    >             #Gather class name or press 'Enter' to quit
    >             class_or_exit = input('Enter course name or Enter to quit: ')
    >     
    >             #Create While loop if 'Enter' is pressed exit and close file
    >             while class_or_exit !="":
    >                 count_files += 1
    >                 grade =(input('Enter grade (interger) achieved: '))
    >                 class_or_exit = input('Enter course name or Enter to quit: ')
    >                 
    >         
    >     
    >             #Write info to the file
    >             outfile.write(str(class_or_exit) + '\n')
    >             outfile.write(str(grade) + '\n')
    >     
    >             #Close file
    >             outfile.close()
    >             print('File was created and closed')
    >             return grade, class_or_exit
    >         
    >     def retrieve():
    >         print('Here is your GPA for the classes you entered:')
    >         outfile = open('grades.txt', 'r')
    >         total = 0.0
    >         count = 0
    >         class_or_exit = outfile.readline()
    >         grade = float(outfile.readline())
    >         
    >         if grade >= 90:
    >             grade = 4.0
    >             count = count + 1
    >             print(f"{class_or_exit:} class" + str + "{grade:.2f}")
    >         elif grade >= 80:
    >             grade = 3.0
    >             count = count + 1
    >             print(f'{class_or_exit:} class'+ str + "{grade:.2f}")
    >          elif grade >= 80:
    >             grade = 2.0
    >             count = count + 1
    >             print(f'{class_or_exit:} class'+ str + "{grade:.2f}")
    >          elif grade >= 80:
    >             grade = 1.0
    >             count = count + 1
    >             print(f'{class_or_exit:} class'+ str + "{grade:.2f}")
    >         
    >     main()
```

Comment: I don't know what a "STRG" error is.  You do have some problems.  In your `print` statement, the colon should be outside the braces:  `{class_or_exit}:`.  Next, I don't know what you're trying to do with `+ str +`, but that's wrong.  In your `create` function, you don't need `str` around `class_or_exit` and `grade`; they are already strings.  Also, you're asking for grades in a loop, but you're only writing the last one to the file, and you're only reading one from the file.

Comment: what is the str in ```print(f"{class_or_exit:} class" + str + "{grade:.2f}")```?

Comment: oh okay i see , well that kind of frustrating to see that the format was {class_or_exit}: when in the book all the example showed this as an example {amount:.2f}. I aprreciate the help .

Comment: the str print(f"{class_or_exit:} class" + str + "{grade:.2f}") is supposed to produce this line of data                                                                                                                                        "{class_or_exit}-(Class entered from the users input recorded in grades.txt file) class GPA is {grade}- (Display grade for the class entered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what I think you meant to do.  Note carefully the differences between this and what you wrote.

```
def create():
    outfile = open('grades.txt', 'w')

    #Gather class name or press 'Enter' to quit
    class_or_exit = input('Enter course name or Enter to quit: ')

    #Create While loop if 'Enter' is pressed exit and close file
    while class_or_exit !="":
        grade =(input('Enter grade (interger) achieved: '))
        #Write info to the file
        outfile.write(class_or_exit + '\n')
        outfile.write(grade + '\n')
        class_or_exit = input('Enter course name or Enter to quit: ')

    #Close file
    outfile.close()
    print('File was created and closed')
    return grade, class_or_exit
    
def retrieve():
    print('Here is your GPA for the classes you entered:')
    outfile = open('grades.txt', 'r')
    total = 0.0
    count = 0
    while True:
        class_or_exit = outfile.readline()
        if not class_or_exit:
            break
        grade = float(outfile.readline())
        count += 1
    
        if grade >= 90:
            total += 4.0
        elif grade >= 80:
            total += 3.0
        elif grade >= 70:
            total += 2.0
        elif grade >= 60:
            total += 1.0

    print("Your GPA is", total/count)

def main ():
    create()
    retrieve()
    
main()
```

Comment: wow to qoute denzel in his not so good recent movie "It's the little things that gets you caught". I see now that I didn't extend parameters of the while loop with the  "while True:" before the " if elif" statements. Thank you very much. Im taking an all online python class and its all from a book. Being a more visual learner, I sometimes get stuck on the real world application of the concepts.

Comment: Now, allow me to point out that you don't really need to write these to a file at all.  You can do the computation in the same loop where you are taking the input.